# Prove this property of characteristic function

Tags: probability-distributions

I have been trying to prove this for some time now but I have reached nowhere.

$\phi(X)$ is the characteristic function of rv X. Prove:
$\phi(X+Y) = \phi(X)\phi(Y)$

if X and Y are independent rv. I tried expanding them as E[$e^{itX}$] but that doesn't lead me anywhere. Please help.

Comment: It would help to know what you're allowing yourself to start from, as this can either be very easy or quite a mess depending on what theorems we may invoke as justification.  Note that the question can easily be reduced to "show that the Fourier transform turns convolution into multiplication."

Comment: Basic definition has been taught to me yet. So i guess its the very easy part maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(X+Y) = E[e^{it(X+Y}] = E[e^{itX}e^{itY}] = E[e^{itX}]E[e^{itY}] = \phi(X) \phi(Y)$.

Comment: Yeah but how could you separate the 2 rv?

Comment: By independence.